# How to fix the size of my React/ElectronJS view?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, electron

### How to fix the size of my React/ElectronJS view?

I have an ElectronJS desktop app that uses React. The view consists of one React component, called `App`. That is called the root component I believe. When I run my program, i. e. the Electron desktop app, the view is nice; the site is rendered and fits well within the window as I intend.

Problem is when I add another React component as a child of `App`, the size of something changes so that a scroll bar appears to my desktop app's window that I don't like. This is because the total size of something has increased. How do I prevent this? Should I define some maximum dimensions for the HTML body or some other HTML element or is there a way in React to fix the maximum size of the root component or what am I supposed to look for here?

Comment: Do you want to hide the overflowing content, or ensure all the content fits within your existing dimensions such that nothing is hidden?

Comment: @Erick I want all the content to fit within.

Comment: This sounds like something that needs to be done by tweaking the styling such that the content can't overflow for your specific app. I don't think there's a one-size-fits-all solution.

Comment: What about the other option, i.e. hiding overflow? @Erick

Comment: You can do that by adding `overflow: hidden` on your root element in CSS. Use `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` attributes if you need to prevent overflow on 1 axis.

Answer (score 0):

**My own solution to my own problem:**

Define the root component's maximum and minimum height in CSS, i. e. the `height` property.